Getting Forbidden Error connecting to Building Connected Pro APIs
I was able to get a 3-legged oauth authentication code and access token.  I am using the refresh token that I received to get a new access token, which is done hourly.  I am using Azure Data Factory to call the APIs.
This is the error message that I receive for the GET Bids API:
{"title":"Forbidden","detail":"BC_PRO_SUBSCRIPTION_REQUIRED"}

Here is the input:
{
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Authorization": "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjY0RE9XMnJoOE9tbjNpdk1NU0xlNGQ2VHEwUV9SUzI1NiIsInBpLmF0bSI6I... "
    },
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/buildingconnected/v2/bids"
}

I got a new access code to get a new access token.  I received the same error with the new token. I verified that my Building Connected account was linked to my Autodesk account.

May I know if other APIs could work (e.g. get projects, bicpackages etc..) . In addition, does the logged user (for 3-legged oauth authentication ) belong to the office that has BuildingConnected Pro? If only the endpoint (get bids) does not work and the logged user has BuildingConnected Pro subscription, ,please  provide the logged user email for us to check. Please send the info to aps.help@autodesk.com with private information, linking to this stackoverflow post
